# I have created pyd file with SWIG and want it to be installable

Tags: python, swig

I have created a simple python module with SWIG (from C++). It is in the form of a .pyd file and a .py file.

I want to be able to give this module to my colleagues so they can install and use it.

I am aware that python modules are often installed using:

```
python setup.py install
```

Perhaps this is the functionality I want, so that my colleagues can run this module from anywhere without worrying about PATH etc.

I also would like to be able to send them an updated module from time to time, which will overwrite the older version when they install it.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand this question, you want a setup.py file to install your module
go through the steps given below :

1. create a directory on Desktop (name it "source" for example)
2. put your .py and .pyc files in it.
3. go to Desktop and create setup.py file and enter the following code

as

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='Some_name',
version='1.0',
author='Author_name',
author_email='abc@xyz.com',
packages=['source']
)
```

4. To use it in any program.

```
import module_name from source
```

hope this helps !